# Hide Form elements using Javascript: correct way to use the name of the element in the script?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I want to use a `checkbox` to hide a text field in a PDF `form`. I want to do this for many `checkbox/text-field` pairs without editing the script for each one. The fields are named identically with a different suffix: `Tax_NA` and `Tax_init` would be one example pair. If the user presses the `N/A checkbox`, it should hide the field for their initials.

**For a single pair, this code worked:**

```
getField("Tax_init").display = event.target.value === "Off" ? display.visible : display.hidden;
```

Now I'm trying to fill in the `hard coded` element name: "`Tax_init`" with a name generated from the name of the `checkbox`:

```
var checkname = string(event.target.name);
var hidename = checkname.replace("NA", "init");
getField(hidename).display = event.target.value === "Off" ? display.visible : display.hidden;
```

This does nothing... but I'm unsure why, or how to use diagnostic tools in Acrobat to pick through the pieces.

I know the top two lines are valid `JS`, but are those functions available in Acrobat? Can I print-to-console or popup to validate each piece? (I VERY rarely write `JS`, and never inside adobe products) Any help is appreciated.

Comment: name is already a string, there is no need to run it through `string()`. Also unless Acrobat or you added a `string()` function, that is likely your error since there is no native string() function, there is a String() function however (case matters in js)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the case error. Removing string()  worked